# Play sound on Android`s WebView

Tags: android, webview

Is there any way to play a sound on Android`s WebView?

audio tag is not implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use embedded Flash, but it won't work on devices that don't support Flash.

I just had a quick try with [Javascript](http://www.jsmadeeasy.com/javascripts/Audio/list_test.asp) and [HTML5](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/everything-you-need-to-know-about-html5-video-and-audio/) embedded sounds, and they didn't work for me in the Android 2.2 browser, but I may have done something wrong. Hopefully someone will be able to provide a better answer.

Comment: Googling seems to indicate that Android doesn't work well with embedded sounds. Apparently Android 2.3 improved things somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the content for the audio url, download it in the background and start a media player separately.

Comment: I dont have access to any java stuff, everything must happen in the VebView )-: